# Problemas con la importación de Enzyme en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

Estoy aprendiendo React, y estoy probando a hacer testing con Enzyme. Dado que tengo la versión 17.0.1 de React, Enzyme aún no tiene compatibilidad por sí misma aún con React y hay que usar un adaptador. Lo he instalado, y así en el fichero `package.json` puedo encontrar lo siguiente:

```
      "devDependencies": {
    "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17": "^0.4.1"
  }
```

Diríamos que todo correcto, que Enzyme está instalado correctamente. Pues bien, ahora me voy al fichero .test dónde quiero ejecutar un test, e importo `shallow` de Enzyme de la siguiente forma `import {shallow} from 'enzyme';`. Sin embargo, al ejecutar el test, me da el siguiente error (adjunto captura de pantalla):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo además un fichero `setupTests.js` con el siguiente código:

```
import Enzyme from 'enzyme'; 
import Adapter from '@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17';

Enzyme.configure({adapter: new Adapter()});
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo para que me detecte la importación? Muchas gracias, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Lo he solucionado y dejo la solución por si le puede servir a alguien más. En el archivo de testing importé: `import './setupTests';` y además ejecuté el comando `npm install enzyme`. No pensaba que el problema pudiera estar ahí, dado que al ejecutar el comando para ver la versión instalada de Enzyme, me aparecía como si estuviera instalado, pero se ve que se instalaría mal. Espero que esto sea de ayuda.

Comment: Sergio buenísimo que pudiste resolver el problema. Te recomiendo que instales enzyme como una dev dependency de tu proyecto, al realizar un `npm install enzyme`  lo instalaste en tu maquina local y no en el project específico, esto significa que cada vez que alguien descargué el repo deberá instalar enzyme manualmente, no bastará con hacer un npm i  general del proyecto (enzyme no estará declarado en tu package.json).